# Tumblr tag RSS feed only shows one item / post

Tags: tumblr, rss

My tumblr tag specific RSS feed only shows the latest post / item : http://onrepeatthisweek.tumblr.com/tagged/overandoverandoverandover2012/rss

It doesn't show all items tagged with that tag (overandoverandoverandover2012). An example of expected behaviour is this tumblr user's RSS feed: http://junesix.org/tagged/photo/rss

I assure you I've tagged 4 posts with that tag, photo evidence attached. Any ideas what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: It might be worth trying another theme, or changing some settings on yours. For starters, what is `Posts per page` set to? (in the Advanced section, when you're customizing the blog) It looks like it only shows 1 post by default on your theme, and it's possible that's applying to the RSS feed, too. I'm wondering because the API seems to work fine - this URL gives all the posts you want, in XML format: http://onrepeatthisweek.tumblr.com/api/read?tagged=overandoverandove